# In R/Shiny how to create others panels with purrr::map

Tags: r, shiny

This is my code.

Why isnt working?

I think I should use `do.call` but idon't know how.
The output should be the first 3 panels and the 4 panels,with a totalof 7 Panels

Any help?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

tabpanel_function <- function(x){
  tabPanel(paste0("Panel",x))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Panela"),
    tabPanel("Panelb"),
    tabPanel("Panelc"),        
     
      1:4 %>% map(~ tabpanel_function(.x))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please don't add a "solution" to the question itself. If you used a different method than the answer below suggested, then post your solution as a separate answer. The community can then upvote which method they found most helpful and you can accept whichever answer you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could work to do call `appendTab` in the server function:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

tabpanel_function <- function(x){
  tabPanel(paste0("Panel",x))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabsetPanel(id = "x",
    tabPanel("Panela"),
    tabPanel("Panelb"),
    tabPanel("Panelc"),        
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  1:4 %>% map(~ tabpanel_function(.x) %>% appendTab("x", .))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Edits

I removed my earlier erroneous assertion that it wouldn't work to do a loop in the ui construction. See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html) for a full demonstration of one way (using `lapply` which has same output as `map`).

Comment: Thanks for your time. I this case how I would add plotOutput into diferent tabpanel?

Comment: Hmm tricky, I think you would want to go down the route of using `insertUI` (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/insertUI.html) to add parts. or consider modularising your shiny app to add more complex things repeatedly (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

Comment: Apologies, turns out I was entirely wrong about not being able to create UI elements from a loop - https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html. Will see if there's a handy fix for your code

Comment: I update the question. This is I include the charts on these new panels. Also I validate your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Haha that's very kind of you to give the points! Glad it all worked out in the end and you've got a good solution there.