# In R/Shiny why my ggplots are not displayed when I am working with modules?

Tags: r, shiny

This is my app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

source('module.R')

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabpanel_UI("mod1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  tabpanel_Server("mod1")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is my module file: 'module.R'

```
tabpanel_function <- function(x,n){     
   
  tabPanel(paste0("Panel",x),               
           plotOutput(paste0("chart_",n))
  )      
}

tabpanel_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(        
    tabsetPanel(id = ns("x"),
                tabPanel("Panela"),
                tabPanel("Panelb"),
                tabPanel("Panelc")     
                
    )      
  )
}

tabpanel_Server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {         
      
      1:4 %>% map(~ tabpanel_function(.x, n = .x) %>% appendTab("x", .))          
      
      output$chart_1 <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color  ='red')
      })
      
      output$chart_2 <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color  ='green')
      })
      output$chart_3 <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color  ='blue')
      })
      
      output$chart_4 <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color  ='yellow')
      })
      
    }
  )
}
```

What am I missing here?

This is a question: [In R/Shiny how to create others panels with purrr::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74532454/in-r-shiny-how-to-create-others-panels-with-purrrmap) that I create but not considering Modules. Turns out that I will need to use modules and the charts are not been displayed. Any help?

Comment: You need to use the namespace (`ns`) in your function.

Comment: `plotOutput(NS(paste0("chart_",n)))` @StéphaneLaurent like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the namespace

```
tabpanel_function <- function(id, x, n){     
  ns <- NS(id) 
  tabPanel(paste0("Panel", x),               
           plotOutput(ns(paste0("chart_", n)))
  )      
}
```

and:

```
1:4 %>% map(~ tabpanel_function(id, .x, n = .x) %>% appendTab("x", .))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to namespace your dynamic `plotOutputs`:

```r
tabpanel_function <- function(x, n, ns){     
  tabPanel(paste0("Panel",x),               
           plotOutput(ns(paste0("chart_",n)))
  )      
}

## [....]

1:4 %>% map(~ tabpanel_function(.x, n = .x, session$ns) %>% appendTab("x", .))
```

[image: Dynamic ggplot within a dynamic panel]